# Validate and identify bad records and field names using xsl templates

Tags: xml, xslt

Is it possible to validate and identify bad records and field names similar to sql*loader using xsl templates?

Implement rules in the below XML like: date format is always 'YYYY-MM-DD' , quantity and price should not have $ symbol, field length of author cannot be more than 250 characters, price should not have more than 2 decimals etc.

```
 <Order>
       <book id="bk101">
          <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
          <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
          <genre>Computer</genre>
          <price>44.95</price>
          <quantity>50</quantity>
          <publish_date>2000-OCT-01</publish_date>
          <deliver_date>2000-11-03</deliver_date>
       </book>
       <book id="bk102">
          <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
          <title>Midnight Rain</title>
          <genre>Fantasy</genre>
          <price>$5.95</price>
          <quantity>25</quantity>
          <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
          <deliver_date>2000-12-28</deliver_date>
       </book>
       <book id="bk103">
          <author>Corets, Eva</author>
          <title>Maeve Ascendant</title>
          <genre>Fantasy</genre>
          <price>5.95</price>
          <quantity>40</quantity>
          <publish_date>2000-11-17</publish_date>
          <deliver_date>2000-NOV-25</deliver_date>
       </book>
       <book id="bk104">
          <author>Corets, Eva</author>
          <title>Oberon's Legacy</title>
          <genre>Fantasy</genre>
          <price>$12</price>
          <quantity>30</quantity>
          <publish_date>2001-03-10</publish_date>
          <deliver_date>2001-05-15</deliver_date>
       </book>
       <book id="bk105">
          <author>Corets, Eva</author>
          <title>The Sundered Grail</title>
          <genre>Fantasy</genre>
          <price>5.95</price>
          <quantity>55</quantity>
          <publish_date>2001-09-10</publish_date>
          <deliver_date>2001-10-12</deliver_date>
       </book>
    </Order>
```

Comment: It's certainly possible but I'd recommend to use XSLT 2.0 because of regex support and other utility functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like what you're describing is similar to [*Schematron*](http://www.schematron.com/), which was an attempt to create a validation system by generating XSLT stylesheets. You might want to investigate that system.

However, the recommended solution these days would be to use the official W3C [XML Schema language](http://www.w3.org/XML/Schema) and an XML parser which supports schema validation, rather than reinventing data validation Yet Again.

Comment: Thanks Keshlam, It is true that it will mimic those utilities but the only consideration is that validation is required only on 5% of the fields. Trying to avoid overhead on rest of fields if possible.       Regards, Gayatri

Comment: I would not say that XML Schema is a utility. It is a natural fit for XML in terms of validation. There is much more overhead if you write validation stylesheets from scratch.

Comment: @MathiasMüller -- I have occasionally seen situations in which people were using systems that considered XSLT their primary "language" and thus wanted to solve everything in XSLT, so I thought it was worth confirming that data validation _can_ be done that way... but I agree, a partial Schema is the right answer architecturally.

Comment: I completely agree with you - my remark was intended as a response to @user3352765 's comment.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for the suggestions. I started looking into the approach suggested.